Suddenly the tf2onnx conversion stopped working in Google Colab. How can I fix this?
Previously, everything was working fine, but just a few days ago, something happened and tf2onnx stopped working in all of my Google Colab notebooks.
This is a test example with https://onnxruntime.ai/
import tensorflow as tf
import tf2onnx
import onnx

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation="relu"))

input_signature = [tf.TensorSpec([3, 3], tf.float32, name='x')]

onnx_model, _ = tf2onnx.convert.from_keras(model, input_signature, opset=13)
onnx.save(onnx_model, "test_model.onnx")

Result:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-820fe10709d8> in <cell line: 13>()
     11 input_signature = [tf.TensorSpec([3, 3], tf.float32, name='x')]
     12 
---> 13 onnx_model, _ = tf2onnx.convert.from_keras(model, input_signature, opset=13)
     14 onnx.save(onnx_model, "test_model.onnx")

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tf2onnx/convert.py in _rename_duplicate_keras_model_names(model)
    329     """
    330     old_out_names = None
--> 331     if model.output_names and len(set(model.output_names)) != len(model.output_names):
    332         # In very rare cases, keras has a bug where it will give multiple outputs the same name
    333         # We must edit the model or the TF trace will fail

AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'output_names'

I also tried using tf2onnx.convert.from_function, but that didn't help either.

In Google Colab, TensorFlow has been updated to version 2.17. Currently, tf2onnx is not working with tensorflow >= 2.16.
The solution: install an earlier version of tf
!pip install tensorflow==2.15.0


This solved it for me:
model.output_names=['output']

